# Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found. How to understand what caused it and how to solve?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ext4, inode

I bought a Centurion Nano from the now defunct Alpha Computers, it ships with Alpha OS (that is essentially a tampered Ubuntu):

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpha OS"
VERSION="1.0.0 Polaris"
ID="alpha-os"
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Alpha OS 1.0.0 Polaris"
VERSION_ID="1.0.0"
HOME_URL="https://alpha.store/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://alpha.store/forums/forum/alpha-product-discussion/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://alpha.store/forums/forum/alpha-product-discussion/"
VERSION_CODENAME=polaris
UBUNTU_CODENAME=polaris
$ uname -a
Linux centurion 4.15.0-29-generic #31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 18 08:54:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Today, after booting up, I noticed that my `/` mount was read-only, I rebooted and got this message:

```
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.
UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
```

on `/dev/sdb2`. Since this is the second time it happens in 1 month I'd like to understand what might be causing it and how do I make sure it doesn't happen again?
The first time I think the system hung up at shutdown and I powered it off. This time the shutdown was completed successfully (or so I thought).

Here more details about the drive:

```
dat@centurion:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       Lenovo SSD SL700 M.2 128G               
    Serial Number:      B0E1077A19DD00000503
    Firmware Revision:  SBFM51.2
    Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
    Supported: 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 
    Likely used: 11
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   16383   16383
    heads       16  16
    sectors/track   63  63
    --
    CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
    LBA    user addressable sectors:  250069680
    LBA48  user addressable sectors:  250069680
    Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Physical Sector size:                   512 bytes
    Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:      122104 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:      128035 MBytes (128 GB)
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
    Form Factor: less than 1.8 inch
    Nominal Media Rotation Rate: Solid State Device
Capabilities:
    LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
    Queue depth: 32
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Standard, no device specific minimum
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 16  Current = 16
    DMA: mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 udma5 *udma6 
         Cycle time: min=120ns recommended=120ns
    PIO: pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4 
         Cycle time: no flow control=120ns  IORDY flow control=120ns
Commands/features:
    Enabled Supported:
       *    SMART feature set
            Security Mode feature set
       *    Power Management feature set
       *    Write cache
       *    Look-ahead
       *    Host Protected Area feature set
       *    WRITE_BUFFER command
       *    READ_BUFFER command
       *    NOP cmd
       *    DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
            SET_MAX security extension
       *    48-bit Address feature set
       *    Device Configuration Overlay feature set
       *    Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
       *    FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
       *    SMART error logging
       *    SMART self-test
       *    General Purpose Logging feature set
       *    WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
       *    64-bit World wide name
       *    WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
       *    {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
       *    Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
       *    Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
       *    Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
       *    Gen3 signaling speed (6.0Gb/s)
       *    Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
       *    Phy event counters
       *    READ_LOG_DMA_EXT equivalent to READ_LOG_EXT
       *    DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
            Device-initiated interface power management
       *    Software settings preservation
       *    DOWNLOAD MICROCODE DMA command
       *    SET MAX SETPASSWORD/UNLOCK DMA commands
       *    WRITE BUFFER DMA command
       *    READ BUFFER DMA command
       *    DEVICE CONFIGURATION SET/IDENTIFY DMA commands
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 65534
        supported
    not enabled
    not locked
        frozen
    not expired: security count
        supported: enhanced erase
    20min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 60min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 
Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 0000000000000000
    NAA     : 0
    IEEE OUI    : 000000
    Unique ID   : 000000000
Checksum: correct
```

Partition mounted as ext4

```
dat@centurion:~$ blkid /dev/sdb2 
/dev/sdb2: UUID="3fd4075e-6d86-4535-9db6-f78b29f942e8" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b4da84e6-2d39-4a40-b732-581a79ae72af"
dat@centurion:~$ cat /etc/mtab | grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

with an ecrypted home directory

```
dat@centurion:~$ cat /etc/mtab | grep home
/home/dat/.Private /home/dat ecryptfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=sumtin,ecryptfs_sig=sumtinelse,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs 0 0
```

And here the details of the recovery process

[image: full recovery process]

SMART (and non SMART) values:

```
dat@centurion:~$ sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-29-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Lenovo SSD SL700 M.2 128G
Serial Number:    B0E1077A19DD00000503
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000000 000000000
Firmware Version: SBFM51.2
User Capacity:    128,035,676,160 bytes [128 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      < 1.8 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   Unknown(0x0ff8) (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Oct 10 11:58:55 2018 PDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Unavailable

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (65535) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x79) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  30) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   6) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     PO-R--   100   100   050    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--C-   100   100   000    -    2404
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--C-   100   100   000    -    283
168 Unknown_Attribute       -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
170 Unknown_Attribute       PO----   094   094   010    -    76
173 Unknown_Attribute       -O--C-   100   100   000    -    1769532
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--C-   100   100   000    -    36
194 Temperature_Celsius     PO---K   067   067   000    -    33 (Min/Max 33/33)
218 Unknown_Attribute       PO-R--   100   100   050    -    0
231 Temperature_Celsius     PO--C-   100   100   000    -    97
241 Total_LBAs_Written      -O--C-   100   100   000    -    1901
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O     51  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O     64  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (64 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Commands not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4             283  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4            2404  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6      3987986978  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x028  6      1577724785  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              33  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              33  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              33  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
0x07  =====  =               =  ===  == Solid State Device Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x07  0x008  1               2  ---  Percentage Used Endurance Indicator
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  4            2  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  4            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0010  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, non-CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x0013  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, non-CRC
```

In syslog I can see an entry for sdb2 remounted but I'm not sure how to interpret it, can't find anything else that looks relevant to me

```
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621017] ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621040] ata3: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621064] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621258] ata3.00: ATA-11: Lenovo SSD SL700 M.2 128G, SBFM51.2, max UDMA/133
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621259] ata3.00: 250069680 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621479] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621588] ata1.00: ATA-10: HGST HTS541010B7E610, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.621589] ata1.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622197] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622455] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      HGST HTS541010B7 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622683] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622684] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622692] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622693] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622699] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622725] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.622957] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Lenovo SSD SL700 51.2 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.623168] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.623280] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 250069680 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.623337] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.623338] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.623379] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.641154]  sda: sda1
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.641429] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.655999]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.657197] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    2.976451] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.487633] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.507287] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.547895] random: fast init done
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.634734] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f00)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.674405] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x00, 0x16, 0x0d.
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.740007] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 10059 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.788005] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6131 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.808299] [drm] RC6 on
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.836004] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 12046 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.884002] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  8275 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.932005] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 13873 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    3.980004] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  9533 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.028005] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 23736 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.076004] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 17173 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.124002] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 27103 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.172003] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 18831 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.220003] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 30098 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.268004] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 22359 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.268701] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 30098 MB/s
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.269390] raid6: .... xor() 22359 MB/s, rmw enabled
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.270077] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.270769] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 49, 75
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.273643] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.284699] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    4.506433] input: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [    9.433983] EXT4-fs (sdb2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [   10.700673] Lockdown: /dev/mem,kmem,port is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [   12.663600] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [   12.790174] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Oct  9 10:21:38 centurion kernel: [   15.800260] EXT4-fs (sdb2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

---

**UPDATE**

This is still happening, I've taken the following random measures in the hope of fixing the situation but to no avail:

- removed the encrypted user home (now the entire disk is a plain ext4 with no ecryptfs)
- removed encryption from swap and moved to a swapfile on a different disk
- updated the kernel to 4.15.0.42.63 amd64 [from: 4.15.0.29.51]

I feel like the problem happens when the system is overloaded but it could easily be the other way around (errors -> read-only fs -> chrome and other apps feel slow).

Comment: It means the filesystem was left in an inconsistent state when you powered off, for example some blocks were/could not be written. Look in your syslog for error messages relating to the disk. What is on `/dev/sdb2`? If you have `smartctl`, get the SMART values.

Comment: @dirkt I'm sure that in one instance I powered off the machine but I'm also sure that in the other instance a proper shutdown had happened. I've added details about sdb2 (it mounts the root fs "/"), SMART (what should I be looking for in there?), and syslog (I'm unsure if that "re-mounted" is normal or not, looks normal since I see it every day???).

Comment: SMART attributes look good (100 is nominal, lower is worse). Don't look only at the newest syslog, look at older ones (you should have a logrotate). You want the error(s) that happened *before* it discovered the problem on reboot. If there are no errors (quite possible given the good SMART values), I don't know the cause.

Comment: @dirkt thanks, the syslogs I've added in the question are similar up to syslog.4 (few days before the problem). At this point I guess I'll wait and see if it happens again =)

Answer (score -1):

1. At the prompt, type `fsck /dev/sda<number>` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (look for the <number> from your logs based on the directory that contains the file system errors)
2. Enter y to all the errors to fix them
3. Exit

Comment: Please read carefully my question, I was asking help in finding the root cause of the issue. Fixing temporarily with `fsck` is no use since it happens daily or even more frequently.

Comment: Most likely your hdd is/was failing. smartctl does indicate likely when your hardware, in this case where your HDD starts to fail. And inodes corruption on a daily or hourly basis does indicate the same. I am sure by now you may have changed the hdd.